# for loop print inside parentheses

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
# IP of servers
a = '11.22.33.44'
b = '55.66.77.88'

# for loop on the servers

for i in (a, b):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    connect = s.connect((i, 25))
    banner = s.recv(1024)
    print banner
    users = ['root', 'user' ]
    # for loop on users list
    for user in users:
        s.send('VRFY ', user, + '\r\n')
        result=s.recv(1024)
        print result
        s.close
```

I can't seem to loop through the ' root, user ' list and print it inside the `s.send()`; what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. At the moment, the `s.send` line has an open parenthesis for which there is no close parenthesis; please edit the question to make the code reflect what's in your actual script (or replace the `"` with `)` to fix the problem).  Note that to show code on SO, type it in (or paste it), then select it, and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent it so it appears as shown now.

Comment: And what is your exact problem?

Comment: Your `s.close` call should be outside your `for` loop; you can't send on a closed socket.  Redo that indentation.

Comment: This isn't what you're asking about, but I notice a common mistake in this code; TCP reserves the right to aggregate or split your send's and recv's.  So banner may be part of a banner or a banner plus some extra stuff.  Similarly, your s.send returns a length indicating how many bytes were actually transmitted; you should use it.  IMO, the easiest way of dealing with these issues is http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~dstromberg/bufsock.html - this allows you to almost ignore the issue, other than needing to flush() and anchor your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`send` receives the following parameters: `socket.send(string[, flags])` (from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send)). You are passing the wrong parameters to `send` - it does not behave like `print`, it assumes the second parameter is flags. Instead, do the following:

```
for i in (a, b):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    connect = s.connect((i, 25))
    banner = s.recv(1024)
    print banner
    users = ['root', 'user' ]
    # for loop on users list
    for user in users:
        s.send('VRFY %s\r\n' % (user,))
        result=s.recv(1024)
        print result
    s.close()
```

Also notice I've fixed the indentation problem with `s.close`, and the missing `()`. Without the brackets the `close` function will not execute, but no error will be generated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your are closing your socket inside the `for` loop. Therefor the second time you iterate through that loop the socket will be closed.